# Can't find method selectpicker

Tags: jquery, select, bootstrap-select

I am running method `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker()` in JavaScript, I'm  getting the following error:

> $(...).selectpicker is not a function

I have included correctly

- jquery
- bootstrap.js and
- bootstrap-select.js

What am I doing wrong?

PLUGINS is constant php ;

```
<?php define('PLUGINS', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/plugins/' );?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= PLUGINS . 'jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= PLUGINS . 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js' ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= PLUGINS . 'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
})
</script>
```

This is printscreen:
[image]

Comment: Could you show more code? Kind of hard to guess right now.

Comment: check all required JS files are loaded no not using console..

Comment: I dont know where is probleme, i try and asinhron library

Comment: possible cause of the problem to be jquery version or version bootstrap.js??
Im download last version of bootsrat and jquery from oficial site

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38706781/310446