# .selectpicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and reference it from javascript, but I always get an error: `.selectpicker is not a function`

Everything I've read about this error says I have a dependency missing or not loaded at the right time, but I'm at a loss as to what I'm missing.

Also, I get the same error when I try `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` from the console, which tells me that it's not an issue with my javascript running before everything's loaded.

Here's the relevant portions of my page:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
...
<select class="selectpicker">
</select>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: there doesn't seen to be a method call without arguments, have you tried with any? http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/

Comment: Yeah I've tried `.selectpicker('refresh');`, same result.

Comment: Are your paths ok? Change them with the CDN links just to make sure

Comment: Chrome developer tools shows them all loading successfully, but I'll try with the CDN links.

Comment: Same result when loading from CDN

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it.  I had a second jquery reference that was re-loading jquery and wiping out the functions added by `bootstrap-select.js`.

Comment: Same issue. Never new jQuery does that.